# Why is my @font-face not working?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am confused as to why this code is not working for me. I am trying to add icons to my  tags, but when I call the font from my files of my website, they don't seem to be working for anything I try to put them in. I am trying to insert an icon into my .showMenu , but for some reason, it isn't working. I have the font files uploaded to my server, and the url's in the @font-face are the correct ones, but it doesn't want to work. Please help!

HTML:

```
<div class="column">

<span class="showMenu" id="showMenu"></span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {

font-weight: normal;

font-style: normal;

font-family: 'icomoon';

src:url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot');
src:url('../fonts/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.svg#typicons') format('svg');

}

.showMenu {

font-size: 22px;

padding-left: 10px;

padding-right: 10px;

background: #ed8151;

font-family: 'icomoon';

border: 1px solid #e86a32;

border-radius: 3px;

}

.showMenu:before {

content: "\e6b8"

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your browser version supports @font-face? You can check at: http://caniuse.com/fontface

Comment: Yes. I have tried it in all of my browsers, which are up to date.

Comment: Are you sure your file path for fonts is on parent directory than your css style lives?

Comment: is the relative path you given correct?

Comment: I have a fonts folder and a css folder in my parent directory, and my fonts are in public_html/fonts/icomoon and my css is in public_html/css/index_style_sheets Would that make a difference, you think? I am just so confused because this font worked yesterday on my site's old version, but now that I have began updating it, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I was playing around, and found a solution. I will answer now

Answer (score 0):

I was putting around, and figured out that each font file needs a full file path, instead of a shortened one.
Here is what it should look like:

CSS:

```
@font-face {

font-weight: normal;

font-style: normal;

font-family: 'icomoon';

src:url('http://yoursite.com/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot');
src:url('http://yoursite.com/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://yoursite.com/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://yoursite.com/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://yoursite.com/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.svg#typicons') format('svg');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your paths are incorrect. Try:

```
src:url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot');
src:url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.svg#typicons') format('svg');
```